# C++ unable to find multiple modes

Tags: c++

My assignment asks me to write a function that takes an array and the size of that array as a parameter, and to find the mode.  If there are multiple modes, I am to find them all, and place them in a vector and print said vector in an ascending order.

For example, if I input the following integers:

```
3, 4, 2, 1, 2, 3
```

Then the output should display

```
2, 3
```

If I input the following integers:

```
1, 2, 3, 4
```

Then the output should display:

```
1, 2, 3, 4.
```

However, my program somehow only finds the first mode and displays it in a really awkward manner.

Here was my input:

```
3, 4, 2, 3, 2, 1
```

And this was the output:

```
3
3
3
3
3
```

Here is my code.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you all for your time!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
   int size;                              //array size
   int* array;                            //array of ints
   int arraycount;                        //counter for array loop
   void findMode(int array[], int size);  //function prototype

//intialize array
   cout << "Enter number of integers ";
   cout << "you wish to input." << endl;
   cin >> size;

   cout << "Enter the integers." << endl;

   array = new int[size];

   for (arraycount = 0; arraycount < size;
   arraycount++)
      cin >> array[arraycount];

//call function
   findMode(array, size);

   return 0;
}

void findMode(int array[], int size) {
   int counter = 1;
   int max = 0;
   int mode = array[0];
   int count;
   vector <int> results;
//find modes
   for(int pass = 0; pass < size - 1; pass++) {
      if(array[pass] == array[pass+1]) {
         counter++;
         if(counter > max) {
            max = counter;
            mode = array[pass];
         }
      }
      else {
         counter = 1;
      }
   }

//push results to vector
   for (count=0; count < size - 1; count++) {
      if(counter == max) {
      std::cin >> mode;
      results.push_back(mode);
      }
   }

//sort vector and print
   std::sort(results.begin(), results.end());
   for (count=0; count < size - 1; count++) {
         cout << mode << endl;
   }
}
```

Comment: don't u want to use multimap?

Comment: I have not learned about multimap in my textbook yet.  Is it doable without?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for the help, I was able to get the code to work.  Turns out the problem was the cin in my vector portion of the function.  Here is my revised code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

#define N 100

void findMode(int x[], int size);       //function prototype
vector<int> results;    //vector

int main(void) {
   int* x;
   int size=0;
   int arraycount;

//intialize array
   cout << "Enter number of integers ";
   cout << "you wish to input."  << endl;
   cin >> size;
   cout << "Enter the integers." << endl;
   x = new int[size];

   for (arraycount = 0; arraycount < size;
   arraycount++)
      cin >> x[arraycount];

//send array and size to function
   findMode(x, size);

   return 0;
}

//findMode function    
void findMode(int x[], int size) {
   int y[N]={0};
   int i, j, k, m, cnt, count, max=0;
   int mode_cnt=0;
   int num;
   int v;
   vector<int> results;
   vector<int>::iterator pos;

//loop to count an array from left to right
   for(k=0; k<size; k++) {
      cnt=0;
      num=x[k]; //num will equal the value of x[k]

      for(i=k; i<size; i++) {   
         if(num==x[i])
            cnt++;              
      }
      y[k]=cnt; //
   }

//find highest number in array
   for(j=0; j<size; j++) {
      if(y[j]>max)
         max=y[j];
   }

//find how many modes there are
   for(m=0; m<size; m++) {
      if(max==y[m])
         mode_cnt++;
   }

//push results to vector
   for (m=0; m < size; m++) {
      if(max == y[m]) {
//after taking out this line the code works properly
//      std::cin >> x[m];      
       results.push_back(x[m]);
      }
   }

//sort vector and print
   std::sort(results.begin(), results.end());
   cout << "The mode(s) is/are: ";
   for (pos=results.begin(); pos!=results.end(); ++pos) {
         cout << *pos << " ";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int size;                              //array size
    int* array;                            //array of ints
    std::vector<int> vecInput;
    int arraycount;                        //counter for array loop
    void findMode(std::vector<int> vec);  //function prototype

    //intialize array
    cout << "Enter number of integers ";
    cout << "you wish to input." << endl;
    cin >> size;

    cout << "Enter the integers." << endl;

    array = new int[size];

    for (arraycount = 0; arraycount < size; arraycount++) 
    {
            int num;
            cin >> num;
            vecInput.push_back(num);
    }


    //call function
    findMode(vecInput);

    return 0;
}

void findMode(std::vector<int> vec) 
{
    std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());
    std::map<int, int> modMap;
    std::vector<int>::iterator iter = vec.begin();
    std::vector<int> results;
    int prev = *iter;
    int maxCount = 1;
    modMap.insert(std::pair <int,int>(*iter, 1));

    iter++;
    for (; iter!= vec.end(); iter++)
    {
        if (prev == *iter)
        {
            std::map<int, int>::iterator mapiter = modMap.find(*iter);
            if ( mapiter == modMap.end())
            {
                modMap.insert(std::pair <int,int>(*iter, 1));
            }
            else
            {
                mapiter->second++;
                if (mapiter->second > maxCount)
                {
                    maxCount = mapiter->second;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            modMap.insert(std::pair <int,int>(*iter, 1));
        }

        prev = *iter;
    }

    std::map<int, int>::iterator mapIter = modMap.begin();
    for (; mapIter != modMap.end(); mapIter++)
    {
        if (mapIter->second == maxCount)
        {
            results.push_back(mapIter->first);
        }
    }

    cout << "mod values are " <<endl;

    std::vector<int>::iterator vecIter = results.begin();
    for (; vecIter != results.end(); vecIter++)
        cout<<*vecIter<<endl;


}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help!  My assignment requires that the function take the array and it's size as parameters however.  I also have not learned about maps so this code is a bit foreign to me.

Comment: i am sorry about those restrictions. While I cannot do the homework for you as it requires, i did review your code. unfortunately your code has logic issues and you need to sort through by debugging using gdb or VS

Comment: you code copy my code and substitute vector for an array, keeping rest of the logic as is. That should you. If that works, please do accept my answer